# Show tooltip on hovering cursors in ace

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am building a collaborative coding environment which has multiple user cursors. I need to show user's nick when other user hover on their cursor in a tooltip (like google docs does). I've tried every way I could think of injecting DOM into the class that I give to the cursor, but tooltips just don't show up.

How can I show a tooltip on the cursor (caret) when a user hovers on it?

Comment: after injecting dom you must reapply tooltip

Answer (score 4):

I know this is late but it might help someone in the future.

I had the same issue in Ace where I firstly couldn't get any tooltip showing, and secondly couldn't get it to show on hover.

**Hover**

Marker nodes have `pointer-events: none` in Ace, so hover is essentially disabled and needs to be re-enabled.

Add `pointer-events: auto` to the marker/caret.
I.e:

```
.ace-multi-cursor {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2720

**Title/Tooltip**

I was using ace-collab-ext. So to add the username above the caret I edited AceCursorMarker.js by adding `<span class="ace-multi-cursor-username" style="background-color: ${this._color}; top: -8px; position: relative;">${this._title}</span>` and recompiling ace-collab-ext.min.js. Below is where I added the title span:

```
// Caret Top
html.push(
  '<div class="ace-multi-cursor ace_start" style="',
  `height: ${5}px;`,
  `width: ${6}px;`,
  `top: ${top - 2}px;`,
  `left: ${left + 4}px;`,
  `background-color: ${this._color};`,
  `"><span class="ace-multi-cursor-username" style="background-color: ${this._color}; top: -8px; position: relative;">${this._title}</span></div>`
);
```

There may be an easier way to do this that suits you, but this way worked for me especially with keeping the background-color permanent, as the attempts I made through js/css didn't persist after initialisation (cursorManager.addCursor).

**CSS**

This is the total css I added to my solution:

```
.ace-multi-cursor {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
.ace-multi-cursor:hover > .ace-multi-cursor-username {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ace-multi-cursor-username {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

My solution ended up looking and functioning exactly like the Google Docs marker, caret and tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's not trivial to do. And requires more code than i can add to this answer. But there are several implementations available on github e.g https://github.com/sharelatex/web-sharelatex/blob/a91ec74d1256ad063cd37693aab620b6f1a6ce0d/public/coffee/ide/editor/directives/aceEditor/highlights/HighlightsManager.coffee#L102 which you can test on https://www.sharelatex.com/